# Script send text to Telegram Channel

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am writing a simple script for tampermonkey that I need to send text that is selected and after pressing the 'p' key to a telegram channel. Nothing appears on telegram and I don't know in which part of the code is the problem
I have tried both entering the telegram channel ID and that of a group where the bot is present.
Is it possible to send it directly to the bot?

```
(function() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        // Check if the 'P' key is pressed and the event target is an editable element
        if (event.key === 'p' && (event.target.tagName === 'INPUT' || event.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA')) {
            const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
            if (selectedText) {
                // Modify this with your bot token and chat ID
                const botToken = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN';
                const chatId = 'YOUR_CHAT_ID';
                // Tried both with -100 at the beginning, with the channel ID starting with 100 and without. 


                GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: `https://api.telegram.org/bot${botToken}/sendMessage`,
                    data: `chat_id=${chatId}&text=${encodeURIComponent(selectedText)}`,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    },
                    onload: function(response) {
                        console.log(response.responseText);
                    },
                });
            }
        }
    });
})();
```